# Save a WriteableBitmap as an image to SharePoint document library

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, document, writeablebitmap

I have a requireemnt in which I have to upload a WriteableBitmap generated as an image in to SharePoint document library. Can anyone please help me ? Thank you.

Comment: Be specific, "Please help me" is not enough information. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Heres an extension method to convert the WriteableBitmap to byte array

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this WriteableBitmap bmp)
{
   int[] p = bmp.Pixels;
   int len = p.Length * 4;
   byte[] result = new byte[len]; // ARGB
   Buffer.BlockCopy(p, 0, result, 0, len);
   return result;
}
```

taken from this blog http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2009/11/convert-encode-and-decode-silverlight.html

To upload it to a document library with the Client OM you can use this tutorial http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/06/10/sp-2010-uploading-files-using-the-client-om-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with SharePoint 2010, you can use the client object model for Silverlight. It's very similar to the client object model for .net, except that it's asynchronous.

[Here's an example](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/10/16/upload-document-silverlight-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply. I need to know how to convert the WriteableBitmap in to a byte array in order to be uploaded to a SharePoint doc. lib.

Comment: Andreas Scharf just added an example on how to do that.